# why doesnt thread.sleep stop at the first catch?

Tags: java, interrupted-exception, interruption

```
public static void main(String s[])
{
    Thread t=Thread.currentThread();
    t.setName("main");
    try
    {
        for(int i=0;i<=5;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(i);
            Thread.sleep(1000);//interrupted exception(System provides error on its own) 
        }
    }
    catch(InterruptedException e)
    {
        System.out.println("main thread interrupted");
    }
}
```

`In my understanding when there is an exception condition the control goes to the catch, implements it and leaves the code. when we use thread.sleep and create a catch for interruptedException why does it keeps on running? instead of quitting . This is the code, when for loop runs for the first time, it prints "0" the when it encounters thread.sleep hence an interruptedexception, shouldnt it go to catch and execute S.O.P and terminate?

Comment: Well...did you trigger an exception that would cause `sleep` to terminate?

Comment: Why would you assume it will terminate if you didn't tell it to?

Answer (score 0):

> why does it keeps on running?

Your program doesn't terminate unless you tell it to. It normally keeps on running. Triggering an exception doesn't change that.

Answer (score 0):

Just calling Thread.sleep doesn't trigger an InterruptedException. For this code to throw an InterruptedException something would have to call interrupt on the thread. Change the code to

```
public class MainInterruptingItself {

    public static void main(String s[]) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        try {
            for(int i=0;i<=5;i++) {
                System.out.println(i);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("main thread interrupted");
        }
    }
}
```

and it will print out

```
0
main thread interrupted
```

What happens here is that calling interrupt sets the interrupt flag on the thread. When Thread.sleep executes it sees that the interrupt flag is set and based on that throws an InterruptedException.